# joing results of 2 queries with different groupByclauses on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries as shown below,

```
query1 = select department as 'Department_name', firstname as 'FirstName', lastname as 'LastName', manager as 'Manager', 
title as 'Title', firstofficer as 'First_Officer', email as 'Email', resourceName as 'Resource Name', 
entitlementName as 'Ent Name', concat(resourcename, entitlementname) AS 'Entitlements', count(distinct uid) 
as 'Total_Common' from outlier_report or1 
group by department, concat(resourcename, entitlementname) 


query2 = select department as 'Department_name', 
count(distinct uid) AS 'Total count of user',
count(distinct resourcename) AS 'Total resource count', 
count(distinct concat(resourcename,entitlementname)) as 'Total  Ent Count' 
from outlier_report or2 group by department;
```

Each of these queries returns different count of results (115 and 125 respectively based on the group by clause)
I have to join the two results so that i have all the fields and 4 counts (1 from 1st and 3 from the other).
How can I do this either using SQL join or using a Java Program to manipulate the separate query results into 1 output csv.

Answer (score 0):

Each query is a "view", so you can just join them. Since you're querying the same table in both queries without filtering (where-clause), an inner join is good:

```
select a.department, a.AA, a.BB, b.CC, b.DD
  from ( select department, AA, BB
           from outlier_report
          group by department, concat(resourcename, entitlementname)
       ) a
  join ( select department, CC, DD
           from outlier_report
          group by department
       ) b on a.department = b.department
```